# Why is my edit form not displaying its data?

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I'm writing a CRUD app using MEAN stack and i'm stuck with the editing stage. When I click on a certain task the edit form is not displaying any data.

This html displays all tasks with a router button to edit the task which should bring you to the edit.component.html with an edit form

```
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let task of tasks">
        <mat-checkbox matListIcon></mat-checkbox>
        <h1 matLine> {{task.title}} </h1>
        <p matLine>{{task.dueDate | date}}
            <span> {{task.note}} </span>
        </p>
        <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon [routerLink]="['/tasks', 'edit', task._id]" color="primary">edit</mat-icon></button>
        <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon (click)="deleteTask(task._id)" color="accent">delete</mat-icon></button>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

This html is the edit-task form that should display all data from the tasks

```
<mat-card>
    <form (submit)='taskEdit(formData)' #formData='ngForm'>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Title" [(ngModel)]='editTask.title' name='editTask.title' #title="ngModel" required>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-error *ngIf="title.invalid && title.touched">
            Please enter a taslk title
        </mat-error>

        <mat-form-field>
            <textarea matInput placeholder="Note" [(ngModel)]="editTask.note" name="editTask.note"></textarea>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field  color="warn">
            <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
            <mat-select  [(ngModel)]="editTask.priLevel" name="editTask.priLevel" multiple required>
                <mat-option value="myDay">My Day</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="important">Important</mat-option>
                <mat-option [(value)]="selectedValue" value="task">Task</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-error *ngIf="dueDate.invalid && dueDate.touched">
            Please choose a category
        </mat-error>
        <div class="action-btn">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="formData.invalid">Create new task</button>
            <button mat-raised-button type="reset" color="primary" (click)="resetForm(formData)">Clear</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</mat-card>
```

Edit Component that receives the data from the routerLink where this.editTask = data

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.scss']
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {

  editTask:any
  hideRequired="true"

  constructor(
    private _httpService:HttpService,
    private _router:Router,
    private _route:ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onlyOne();
  }

  onlyOne(){
    this._route.params
    .subscribe((params:Params) => {
      this._httpService.oneTask(params['id'])
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.editTask = data;
        console.log('All data from one single task', this.editTask)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Server

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {
  private serviceUrl = "http://localhost:8000/tasks"
  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { }
  getAllTasks(){
    return this._http.get(this.serviceUrl);
  }
  oneTask(id:Number){
    return this._http.get('/tasks/task/'+id)
  }
}
```

Controller

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Task = mongoose.model("Task");

module.exports = {

    oneTask: (req, res) => {
        id = req.params.id
        Task.findOne({_id:id}, (err, task) => {
            if(err){
                res.json({error: "Error, cannot find single task", err});
            } else {
                res.json({success: "Success, found single task", task});
            }
        })
    }
}

After I click on the edit button in the task.component.html you should be able to see all the data from that task on edit.component.html.
```

Comment: If the problem is still not resolved then request to share the code in the StackBlitz where *I/we* can reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors:

1) You need to create a route, something like this;

```
{path: 'tasks/edit/:id', component: EditComponent}
```

2) replace

```
<button mat-icon-button><mat-icon [routerLink]="['/tasks', 'edit', task._id]" color="primary">edit</mat-icon></button>
```

with this (the format of route):

```
<button mat-icon-button><mat-icon [routerLink]="['/tasks/edit',task._id]" color="primary">edit</mat-icon></button>
```

Comment: First I will like to thank you for your response. It's my fault that I wasn't very thorough with all my code/explanation of what code I have already written. I did already create a path that leads to my EditComponent. I have also created a server that handles the task id to grab the whole object. So when I console.log data I do get the whole object, but I also get an error that comes with it

[![error][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMi0K.png

Comment: can you tell me what console.log(data) are showing? @K.Pham

Comment: Try initializing editTask with a new task, Surely angular tries to link the object properties before your server responds @K.Pham

Comment: Or add this on your form <form (submit)='taskEdit(formData)' #formData='ngForm' *ngIf="editTask">

Comment: The error I get is the link i put in my first comment. As for adding the *ngIf it got rid of the error and the form still shows, but didn't fix the problem .

Comment: Your problem is that initially you cannot use editTask because it is not initialized and when you do {{task.title}} you are doing something like {{undefined.title}}, you have two options, or you initialize it or wait for the server answer you to show the form @K.Pham